# How to get FULL type name in python?

Tags: python

Printing result of `type()` in Python sometimes reveals type name that is not in current scope. For example, following code will display `"<type 'frame'>"`

```
import inspect
a = inspect.currentframe()
print( type( a ) )
```

But there is no `frame` type in current scope! If i try to use it in interactive interpreter, i get an error:

```
>>> frame
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined
```

So is it any way to get a "fully qualified" type name like "inspect.something.frame" so i can refer it in my code?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, `__module__` is not working too:

```
>>> type( a ).__module__
'__builtin__'
```

Comment: do you mean `>>> frame` instead of `>>> type`?

Comment: I don't think it's doable. As one answer below mentions the `__module__` attribute might be helpful in getting a partial solution but the general case isn't solvable.

Comment: What is the actual use case here? What kind of code are you trying to write that you cannot write without going from the string `"<type 'frame'>"` to the type `frame` (and without access to the type object you got the string from)?

Comment: That should be `type(a).__module__`

Answer (score 3):

```
"What's in a name? That which we call a frame 
 By any other name would smell as sweet."
```

---

If you are looking for the Python object that corresponds to the type of a frame, you could use:

```
In [38]: import types

In [39]: types.FrameType
Out[39]: <type 'frame'>
```

---

Of course, this is just a different way of writing `type(a)`:

```
In [42]: import inspect

In [43]: a = inspect.currentframe()

In [44]: types.FrameType == type(a)
Out[44]: True
```

---

If you look inside the `types` module, you'll find that `types.FrameType` is defined this way:

```
try:
    raise TypeError
except TypeError:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    TracebackType = type(tb)
    FrameType = type(tb.tb_frame)
    del tb
```

All they are doing is finding an instance of `frame` and defining `FrameType` to be the `type` of this instance.

That is essentially what you are doing when you define

```
MyFrameType = type(a)
```

So the conclusion is: to get your hands on the type of an instance, just call `type(obj)`. You don't need to know *aprior* anything else.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to figure out object type without **foreknowledge** of `types.FrameType`. Given only `a` object from my example, **without** knowledge that `frame` is `types.FrameType` - how can you figure this out?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `type(a)`. An object is an object, and you've found the object your desire. Just *define* `FrameType = type(a)` if you wish. There is no need to know *aprior* about `types.FrameType`. If you look inside the `types` module you might be shocked to find that this is essentially how they define `types.FrameType`.

Comment: Given `frame` - how can you find out that it's inside `types` and called `FrameType`?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just use `type(frame)`. It is just as good as `types.FrameType`. There is nothing that `types.FrameType` can do that `type(frame)` can not.

Comment: I think the confusion here is a more general one: The OP is expecting to be able to reconstruct `type(a)` given `repr(type(a))`. As a general rule, if the `repr` is enclosed in angle brackets, you can't use it to programmatically reconstruct the value. So, just keep `type(a)` around in the first place, instead of trying to guess what `<type 'frame'>` might refer to.

Comment: @unutbu For example, i have a code that received object and performs different actions according to object type. How can i use `==` to compare object with `frame` if i don't know that i need to put `types.FrameType` to the right of `==`?

Comment: To check if `obj` is an instance of `frame` use `isinstance(obj, type(a))`.

Comment: @EyeofHell: You should never be comparing types using `==`, and you should rarely be looking at types in the first place, and I can't imagine any case where you'd need to do such type-switching without knowing ahead of time the types you were switching on. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Or if `obj` is a class and you want to know if it is a subclass of `frame`, then use `issubclass(obj, type(a))`. (Btw, `issubclass(type(a), type(a))` is `True`.)

Comment: @unu creating stack trace just to check type of an object seems not very pythonic.

Comment: Yet, if you `import types` that's exactly what the developers do. (I agree that I was very repulsed when I first looked inside the `types` module, but given that that is the way the developers have defined `FrameType`, I don't think we have any other choice.)

Comment: @unutbu: But that's an implementation detail. As a user, you just look it up in the docs and use it, and you don't care how the `types` module is implemented.

Comment: This entire question is implementation-specific. In Python implementations without stackframe support, `inspect.currentframe()` returns `None`. Indeed, the notion of frame is not part of the Python language specification, but is instead an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to do this.  Generally, you can just use:

```
x.__module__ + '.' + x.__name__
```

However, this won't work if the object isn't accessible from its module; for example, this can happen if the module uses `del` to remove the object from its namespace.

For class methods, [PEP 3155](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) introduces the `__qualname__` attribute; but that also won't help in this case.  `type(a).__module__` is `'__builtin__'`, but `frame` is not a name in the `__builtin__` module.  This is fairly common with types that are implemented in C.

In this case, you have to know that the `frame` type is in the `types` module:

```
from types import FrameType as frame
```

Comment: This is not fair :). Where is no way for me "to know" that `frame` is actually `FrameType` from `types`. Is it any way to figure this out without foreknowledge?

Comment: @EyeofHell: You don't need to know that, because you never need to discover `types.FrameType` dynamically. That definition is there when you know you need a FrameType, and need to know what type that is. On the other hand, if you already have a frame `a`, all you need is `type(a)` to get the type. Re-read unutbu's answer; it explains everything in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

unutbu's answer already includes all of the specific details here, but let's step back a bit.

What you're trying to do is, in general, impossible. Not just for frames, but for *anything*.

`print(x)` implicitly prints out `str(x)`. If you're lucky, this is the same as `repr(x)`, but often it gives you something human-readable rather than computer-usable.

You can, of course, get around that by just using `repr(x)` instead of `str(x)`. But that *still* doesn't help.

It's a nice rule of thumb that `repr(a)` gives you either something useless enclosed in angle brackets, or something that can be `eval`uated back to a value that `== a`. But even that can't be relied on; it's just a rule of thumb.

And in this case, once you've got `<type 'frame'>`, that's clearly the first kind of `repr`, and it is useless.

But there's good news: All you need to do is keep `x` around, instead of keeping `repr(x)` around and trying to reconstruct `x` later.

Or, in this case, keep `type(a)` around, and you have the frame type.

Comment: Instanciating stack trace just to check type of given object seems not very pythonic to me :(. `isinstance( something, types.FrameType )` reads much more better. But it requires foreknowledge where `frame` is hidden.

Comment: @EyeofHell: Yes, if you know statically, in advance, that you want to check for frames, use `types.FrameType`. And the way you find that is by reading the docs. It's only if you want to do things dynamically that you need to programmatically figure it out.